# Postgresql query problems for nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I am making an app with **node.js**, using the **express** framwork, woth **postgresql** as my database.

I have to insert some values into my database, and some of them have quotes. e.g. **Tony's Seafood Restaurant**. I cannot insert values like this.

I tried

```
name.replace('\'', '\\\'');
```

and also

```
name.replace("'", "\'");
```

but no success.

Problem is the postgresql server formats queries before running them. If the query look like this in my code,

```
insert into venues values (nextval('venue_venueid_seq'),'"+name+"','"+api+"','"+location+"','"+latitude+"','"+longitude+"','"+category+"','"+category_generalized+"')
```

then postgresql formats it like this (i found it by printing the client.query object)

```
insert into venues values (nextval(\'venue_venueid_seq\'),\'Tony\'s Seafood Restaurant\',\'Google Places\',\'18863 California 1, Marshall\',\'38.146777\',\'-122.882987\',\'restaurant,food,establishment\',\'Eatery,Eatery,establishment\')
```

You see postgresql already places slashes before the starting and the ending quotes of my string, so the escape slashes I programatically inserted in the middle of the string are not working.

How can I insert values like this? Please help.

Comment: Does postgres allow you to forego explicitly listing the names of the columns receiving the inserted data values?

Comment: the problem is still there even if i explicitly include column list in insert query...morover i am getting same problem for select query

Comment: What happens if you don't programatically escape your apostrophes? \Tony's Restaurant\ ?

Comment: See if this page helps you. Check out the section where the inserted values are passed as parameters: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres.  `client.query("INSERT INTO beatles(name, height, birthday) values($1, $2, $3)", ['John', 68, new Date(1944, 10, 13)]);`

Comment: Using parameterized queries like you showed was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `pg-escape` module to handle this case. This module also have some other escaping methods those can be usefull.

**Installation**

npm install pg-escape

**Example**

var sql = escape('INSERT INTO %I VALUES(%L)', 'books', "O'Reilly");

console.log(sql);

Comment: The problem was in manual query formatting - never do that! Use the query-formatting methods, according to the documentation, and you won't have any problems. There is no need bringing another module into this.